# Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'touchesBegan'

Tags: ios

I am getting the following error

Use of undeclared identifier 'touchesBegan'

In the following code which is under @implementation

```
    SKTexture* eyeTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"eye1"];
eyeTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* eyeTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"eye2"];
eyeTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    SKAction* flap = [SKAction repeatActionForever: [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[eyeTexture1,     eyeTexture2] timePerFrame:0.2]];

_eye = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:eyeTexture1];
[_eye setScale:2.0];
_eye.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 4, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[_eye runAction:flap];

}





-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
```

Comment: this looks like a missing `}` somewhere in your code. Format your code, and look for it.

Comment: That has helped, but the } is now getting the error of :Control reaches end of non-void function.

Comment: That's a different problem - compiler tells you that you are missing a `return` somewhere, but the function/method is not `-(void)`. You should probably delete this question, because it is probably a very simple syntax error in the code that you are not even showing.

Comment: You're not showing enough context.

Answer (score 0):

I've met this problem before. Did you missing } for the method which is above the touchesBegan? Add in and it will be OK.